# C Language - How to make rand value a constant for masking and unmasking in a hangman game

Tags: c, random, data-masking

I am doing a project for a small hangman game that picks from a random selection of words and the user has to guess what the word is with a scanf inputting letters with a counter that builds a hangman, resulting either in a game over or win.

The issue lies in that when using the word[x] it isn't accepting it as "Expression must have a constant value", this error comes up in;

```
int mask[m];
```

and

```
mask[i] = 0;
```

All I can guess is that the rand function is the issue, but I have no idea how to fix it, anyone has a clue?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string>
#define ARRAY_SIZE 10

int main()
{
    //randomwordgenerator
    char word[ARRAY_SIZE][200] = { "tiger", "lion", "elephant", "zebra", "horse", "camel", "deer", "crocodile", "rabbit", "cat" };


    int x = 0;
    srand(time(0));

    x = rand() % ARRAY_SIZE;

    system("pause");

    //masking and unmasking word
    char m = strlen(word[x]);//will count the number of letters of the random word
    int mask[m];
    for (int i = 0; i < m; ++i) {
        mask[i] = 0;
    }

    return 0;
}
//Still have to do the loop and counter that prints out hangman
```

Answer (score 3):

Prior to C99, defining an arrays requires the size to be a constant expression (an expression that can be computed at compile time). Here you tried to define an array with the result of `strlen(word[x])`, which is only known at run time.

Since C99, C supports [Variable Length Arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) which allows the size to be known at runtime. However, since C11, this is only an optional feature and compilers are no longer required to support it.

If you can not use VLAs (e.g. because you are using MSVC), you can always put a fixed limit on the size of the `mask` array (`int mask[200];`) as you did for the `word` array.

Comment: So I just edit (int mask[x];) into (int mask[200];) and that should solve the problem since rand is being computed at the end so the program has no idea what to do with it at the start?

Comment: Yes. Replacing `int mask[x]` by `int mask[200]` will solve your compilation problem. But the reason is not that the size is chosen "at the end" by selecting a string using `rand`, rather that the size is not known at compile time. `200` is a constant (integer literal), `ARRAY_SIZE` is a preprocessor macro that will be replaced by the constant `10` but `x` is computed by the program at runtime, so the compiler does not know anything about its actual value and can not allocate the necessary space for the `mask` array.